# How to create a boolean string from a user-inputted text to run a Google XRay Search?

Tags: linkedin-api, google-search

How do I create a code to convert a series of keywords from a User Input Text field to a Google Search String?
(Check Screenshot)
User will be able to create a google xray search string using this form and the result will be something like this:

Form Input:
Job Title: PHP Developer
Location & Keywords to include: Sunnyvale, PHP, Wordpress, Magento
Keywords to exclude: recruiter
Current Company: paypal

Result Boolean String:

[http://www.google.com/search?q=+"PHP+Developer"+"Sunnyvale"](http://www.google.com/search?q=+%22PHP+Developer%22+%22Sunnyvale%22) AND "PHP" AND "Wordpress" AND "Magento" -"recruiter" -intitle:"profiles" -inurl:"dir/+"+site:[www.linkedin.com/in/+OR+site:www.linkedin.com/pub/+"Current+%2A+paypal+%2A+"](http://www.linkedin.com/in/+OR+site:www.linkedin.com/pub/+%22Current+%2A+paypal+%2A+%22)

User will  be able to copy this url and paste it into Google or a button should be added which will show the same result. So that when user will click on it, it will automatically open a new window in Chrome and will have the same search result.

Javascript but no success